# Laravel permission issue with caching

Tags: laravel

I use Centos 7.

I have an issue regarding OS permission. My all `supervisor` processes work as `root` user.

```
[root@ip-172-31-9-100 example.com]# ll storage/framework/cache/data/
drwxr-xr-x 3 apache apache 16 Sep 22 11:29 00
drwxr-xr-x 5 apache apache 36 Sep 26 10:27 02
drwxr-xr-x 3 apache apache 16 Sep 23 15:14 03
drwxr-xr-x 3 apache apache 16 Sep 22 11:30 04
drwxr-xr-x 3 apache apache 16 Sep 22 12:55 05
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     16 Sep 22 10:47 06
drwxr-xr-x 3 apache apache 16 Sep 23 16:39 08
```

My `supervisor` configuration:

```
[program:api-horizon]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=php /var/www/html/example.com/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
redirect_stderr=true
stopwaitsecs=86400
```

`apache apache` is created by laravel project and `root root` is created by `supervisor` processes. When laravel project wants to user `root root` permission cache file, I get an permission error:

> [2021-09-23 09:00:05] production.ERROR: Unable to create lockable
> file:
> /var/www/html/example.com/storage/framework/cache/data/e9/a0/e9a039230d7835a69038c5a295dc7bfa88213125.
> Please ensure you have permission to create files in this location.
> {"userId":605,"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Unable to
> create lockable file:
> /var/www/html/example.com/storage/framework/cache/data/e9/a0/e9a039230d7835a69038c5a295dc7bfa88213125.
> Please ensure you have permission to create files in this location. at
> /var/www/html/example.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/LockableFile.php:73)

Please, help me to fix this permission issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your configuration to run as `apache` user:

```
[program:api-horizon]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=php /var/www/html/example.com/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=apache //instead of root
redirect_stderr=true
stopwaitsecs=86400
```

Then restart `supervisor`:

```
sudo supervisorctl reread && sudo supervisorctl update && sudo supervisorctl restart all
```

This way, supervisor will run as `apache` user instead of `root`. The files it will create will be readable, writable by `apache` which should fix your problems.

Technically, the role of Supervisor is to ensure a process is always running. You have to configure it the way it would run if you were executing it manually.

In your case, `php /var/www/html/example.com/artisan horizon` should be executed by the user who own the project, which is `apache`.

If you don't, then everything Horizon does will be done by `root`.

Horizon will work - `root` can do anything - but when your `apache` user will try to retrieve data or write directories that `root` created... you guessed it, `permission denied`.

---

Don't forget to fix your permissions, because the `root` owned directories and files will stay and cause errors, even after you changed the configuration.

Execute `sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/example.com/` so everything inside this directory is owner by `apache` again.